# mysql order with many criterias on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort a visitor list after some different criteria and got stuck, as I can't figure out, how to do this.

I have a queue of people who check in first, and out of that the list is generated. The client is marked as showedUp, if he comes to the door (after called with his number on the list). If someone comes late, he must be at the end of the list. Another thing is, the list starts everytime with a different number.

```
Day 1 -> List from 1 to 160
Day 2 -> List from 33 to 160, 1 to 32
Day 3 -> List from 65 to 160, 1 to 64
```

If someone comes late, meaning the number after him is already called, he should be added to the end of the list, like 1 to 160, 10 was late, as 20 was already called, it should be 1 to 160, 10. If there is another starting number it should be 33 to 160, 1 to 32, 10. The criteria here is: if a placeNr after your number is already called (showedUp), than you be at the end of the list.

Tables

```
clients (id, name, placeNr)
visits (id, pid, checkInTime, showedUp, showedUpTime)
```

Select

```
SELECT clients.id AS id, visits.id AS visitId, clients.placeNr AS placeNr, clients.name AS name 
FROM clients, visits 
WHERE clients.id = visits.pid AND visits.checkInTime >= '1447286401' AND visits.checkInTime <= '1447372799' 
ORDER BY clients.placeNr < '1', if(visits.showedUpTime < visits.checkInTime, clients.placeNr, 1), ttc.placeNr
```

So how do I get the late showers at the end of my list?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Sample data in the two tables and desired results would help explain the problem (or better yet a SQL Fiddle).

Comment: @Paddy `placeNr` --> expalin this field..

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your logic, you need to specify whether or not someone is late.  The following is the structure that you want for this type of query.  I think I've captured the rules in your question:

```
select v.id, v.id AS visitId, c.placeNr, c.name,
       (case when v.showedUpTime >
                  (select min(v.checkInTime)
                   from visits v2 join
                        clients c2
                        on v2.pid = c2.id
                   where date(v2.showedUpTime) = date(v.showedUpTime) and
                         c2.placeNr > c.placeNr
                  )
             then 1 else 0 end) as IsLate
from clients c join
     visits v
     on c.id = v.pid
order by date(v.showedUpTime),
         isLate,
         c.placeNr;
```